# Use a different *.config file, depending on IIS application pool .NET version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm looking for a way to programmatically determine which version of the .NET Framework an application pool is using in IIS, at runtime, and for a website application to then use that information to choose which *.config file it should use.

Is it possible? I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Because I want to provide a single installer for a website application that needs as little configuration as possible. The people who'll be installing the application in question aren't as code-minded as "us lot", and don't want to have to delete the lines of config that are required in .NET 2.0, but superfluous in .NET 4.0. I'm guessing I've asked a stupid question, given the two (so far) down votes...

Comment: Why not just target at 2.0?

Comment: Because the "scripting" sectionGroup of the .config file is required in .NET 2.0 and needs not to be there in .NET 4.0, surely people are familiar with this issue? "There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined" or similar.

Comment: And I can't guarantee the end users will have the .NET 4.0 Framework installed, so I'd like a "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: It sounds like you need to stick to things that are supported in .NET 2.0 since you can't guarantee 4.0 is installed. Unless you've got code that takes advantage of 4.0, why even bother supporting it? This is going to be more of a headache than just requiring 2.0. (Unless you've got multiple code bases, but it's tough to tell that from what you've posted)

Comment: But none of this makes sense. You compile your code for framework 4.0 or 2.0. You can't run 2.0 code on a 4.0 machine and vice versa. So you can change the config as much as you want it won't work unless it's installed in the environment that's it's compiled against.

Comment: Thanks for all of your responses. I'm not sure why the question was marked down though. It showed a lack of understanding on my part, admittedly, but don't **questions** by their very nature do that? Just because I asked something stupid, doesn't mean it was a bad thing to ask, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a good way to do this per application pool. This would be tough to manage, and would easily break when app pools are upgrades are performed, and people wouldn't know why. This isn't generally the way most do this, so I would avoid it if possible. Instead, I suggest the following alternatives:

For development and testing purposes, we use the [NConfig](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NConfig/) library (`Install-Package NConfig`) to allow for different configurations per hostname.

However, we don't use it in production since we would have to maintain configurations for every server in the web farm, which often are started via automated processes anyway so we don't even know hostnames most of the time. So for managing settings per *environment* in those cases, we use msdeploy transform configurations. (There are lots of tutorials around the net on how to use those.) It also supports multiple configuration settings via profiles, if you need them.

Also, in your comments you mention something about having to run a installer to install a site that works in .Net 2.0 and 4.0. I'm guessing that means you want your configuration to be different depending which the site is installed on? I would discourage that. It would be easier to get it to install and run in .Net 2.0 (not 4.0) if there are important differences that you can't get to work in both (which would be the better option).

In the end though, there is no 'easy' install for a web site. You have to get the .Net versions (user may not even have 2.0 if they have an old enough Windows :( ), security settings, IIS versions, IIS plugins, often some kind of SQL, connection strings, and so on. If an MSI install of this app is imperative though, then know it's not going to be easy, and you'll most likely need to customize a lot of the process.

Answer (score 1):

You might have enough in looking at the value of property [`System.Environment.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

which basically:

> Gets a Version object that describes the major, minor, build, and
>   revision numbers of the common language runtime.

Based on that you can load your config and/or load new application domain with the new configs.